# Find if device is touch screen then apply touch event instead of click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

I am creating a phonegap application, but as I came to know that it takes 300MS to trigger click event instead of touchevent.

I don't want to apply both event. Is there any way to know if it's touch device without modernizer.

Here is jquery code for assumption

```
$('#id').on('click',funciton(e){
  alert('id was clicked');
});
```

is there anyway to do it with pure JS/jQuery as phonegap application already takes more memory I want to use less library as I can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I mean really you should `Modernizr` but...

```
var supportsTouch = 'ontouchstart' in window || navigator.msMaxTouchPoints;
var eventType = supportsTouch ? 'ontouchstart' : 'click';
```

Then declare your event listeners as such:

```
$('#id').on(eventType, function(e) {
  alert('id was clicked');
});
```

Comment: I think it will attach but can you tell me how much cross browser compitability.

Comment: make sure to change the spelling on function in the above. I tried an edit on this post but it wont let me as it was not a big enough edit!!

Answer (score 2):

This should eliminate the 300ms delay and trigger simulated clicks on desktop and touch devices :

```
$('#id').on('mousedown touchstart', function() {

    $(this).one('mouseup touchend', function() {
        alert('id was clicked');
   });
});
```

If the item has a link in it (normally triggered by `click`), it would need some adaptation :

```
$('#id a').on('mousedown touchstart', function() {

    var destination = this.attr('href');

    $(this).one('mouseup touchend', function() {
        if (destination) window.location = destination;
    });
});
```

---

Edit - already having an accepted answer, this reply was more of an additional note. But nirmal was correct in the comments that touch devices emulating mouse events might lead to complications. The above code is therefore better suited to use with touch events only.

To be more complete with this answer, I'll post my approach for handling both touch and mouse events simultaneously. Either sequence will then trigger a custom event named `page:tap`. Listening for these simulated clicks can then be done as follows:

```
$(subject).on('page:tap', function() { ... });
```

Mouse and touch events are separated and any emulation triggering additional events is prevented by adding a class to `body` in between `touchend` and `click`, removing it again when the latter occurs.

```
var root = $('body'), subject = '#example_1, #example_2';

$(document).on('mousedown touchstart', subject, function(e) {

  if (e.type == 'mousedown' && e.which != 1) return; // only respond to left clicks
  var mean = $(e.currentTarget);

  mean.one('mouseup touchend', function(e) {
    if (e.type == 'touchend' && !root.hasClass('punch')) root.addClass('punch');
    else if (root.hasClass('punch')) return;
    mean.trigger('page:tap');
  });
})
.on('click', subject, function() {

  root.removeClass('punch');
  return false;
});
```

One could also choose to add the class to the active element itself or `html` for example, that depends a bit on the setup as a whole.

Comment: It will apply 2 events, isn't it.

Comment: Thanks it helped me a lot in expanding my knowledge, I really appreciate your answer.

Comment: Glad I could provide some additional info (since there was an accepted answer already). :-)

Comment: Answer got an update, you were correct earlier because of touch devices emulating mouse events. This approach should be pretty bullet proof.

Answer (score 1):

Apply [fastclick](https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick) to your application. You'll find a .js file and a documentation over there. The shortest (jQuery) way of implementing that would be:

```
$(function() {
    FastClick.attach(document.body);
});
```

If you don't use jQuery, you can choose the other way:

```
if ('addEventListener' in document) {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        FastClick.attach(document.body);
    }, false);
}
```

Let me know if you need further help!

This is the **[direct link to the fastclick.js file](https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick/blob/master/lib/fastclick.js)**

Comment: Is there anyway to do it with pure JS/jQuery as I don't want to use much library as possible due to memory consumption issue.

Comment: @Sithys Asker has already said that he don't want to load any library. 'is there anyway to do it with pure JS/jQuery as phonegap application already takes more memory I want to use less library as I can.'

Comment: Like you see Tushar it was edited - before the edit, no word about that ;-) 

You shouldn't worry about memory issues. If your application is so big that you have memory problems you should think about native programming. Cordova is a webview. We have Applications with tons of librarys and absolutely no memory issues are known. Just looked it up, biggest application for one of our customers: 27 librarys. (working like a charme)

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
var clickEvent = ((document.ontouchstart!==null)?'click':'touchstart');
$("#mylink").on(clickEvent, myClickHandler);
```

Answer (score 0):

for anyone coming here in 2021, use [pointers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Pointer_events) events, and check `pointerType` to distinguish between mouse, touch, and pen.