# jQuery.fn.extend function called on load once after the script loads

Tags: javascript, jquery

The function **clickOrTouch** is called once after the script loads.

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
clickOrTouch: function(handler) {
    console.log("in clickOrTouch: " + this);
    var event = ('ontouchstart' in document) ? 'touchstart' : 'click';
    $(document).on(event, this, handler);
}
});
```

**EDIT 1**

The fiddle is at http://jsfiddle.net/HCUYW/101/ . Reload and the output **"in clickOrTouch: "** is printed to the console.

```
$('.invite_button').clickOrTouch(function() {console.log("test");});
```

The class **.invite_button** does not exist as it is added dynamically. Does the call to **clickOrTouch** function is normal behaviour ?

Comment: No it does not, the plugin can't run on elements that aren't there.

Comment: @adeneo Please look at the Edit, updated the link to fiddle where the behaviour can be reproduced.

Comment: @Talespin_Kit run it after the elements are added, the problem isn't that the function isn't there it's that the elements aren't there.

Comment: In case that you haven't heard about it, jQuery introduced a new event system which is pointer events. It could be helpful for you. I suggest that check this link: https://github.com/jquery/PEP

Comment: @AdemIlhan Thanks. But i am looking for simple system where touchevent is used on android webview and click event is used on desktop browsers for buttons.

Comment: I wouldn't assume that when a device has touch support, the user won't be able to use a mouse anyway. But the comparison isn't quite right - a click gets emulated on mobile and *is* a `touchstart` chained by a `touchend`, not a separate event. One should really check the current input and then decide if it is touch or mouse. But what's the exact question though? Works as expected on Firefox desktop.

Comment: @Shikkediel The idea is to prevent the 300ms delay on the mobile browsers. https://github.com/alexblack/google-fastbutton seems to be the solution.  But the problem is it google-fastbutton does not work for desktop browsers as it throws erros on desktop browsers. Trying to find a solution which works on both mobile and desktop browsers without having to do specific coding for each(as in if (mobile) {..} else {...}).

Comment: Let me refer to this first : http://stackoverflow.com/a/29747779/3168107. In short - if you program your clicks as chains of `mousedown` and `mouseup` or `touchend` and `touchstart` the delay will be gone. Using clicks often won't work because as mentioned before, on mobile they are an emulation of the touch events. The code in the link could probably use an update for unbinding by the way.